# twitter search api - selecting only text not user

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-search

if I want to search for q = 'dreamer' I would like to get **only** the tweets having the searched word (dreamer) and not the username having in their username the searched word.
As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEk0l.png) when I searched for dreamer I got some tweets having in their text the world dreamer but also some tweets from username who have dreamer as a part of their username. How can I filter so I can only have the tweets having the researched word (and not users).
Thank you

Comment: There's no way to do this in the API - the best you can achieve is to specifically exclude individual users e.g. `-from:dreamer -from:dreamer2`